# How do I add to odd index values in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

I have to process the list to add an amount to every odd position. For example, if I start with

```
def main():
    L = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
```

and have to add 5 to each odd position, the output should be

```
    L = [1,8,5,12,9,16]
```

I'm stumped as to where to begin, I am supposed to use indexing and a for loop but everything I try is not working. Here's what I have so far

```
def main():
    L = [3,12,9,5,7,6,8]
    i=0
    while i < len(L):
      if i%2 == 1:
         print L[i]
         i = i+5
       elif i%2 == 0:
         print L
```

Comment: do you need to print the values? To return them?

Comment: That's and infinite loop :o

Comment: `L = [x+5 if i%2==1 else x for i,x in enumerate(L)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), one of python's greatest features:

```
L = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
L2 = [L[i]+5 if i%2 else L[i] for i in range(0,len(L))]
```

, or, as @matiasg suggested:

```
L2 = [L[i] + 5 * (i % 2) for i in range(len(L))]
```

Comment: shorter: `[L[i] + 5 * (i % 2) for i in range(len(L))]` ;-)

Comment: This is the only thing that ended up working for me! I remember learning this a few months ago but didn't think to use it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

You can splice your list. Splicing is making assignments to indexes of your original list from another source list. This "other source list" can come from a simple list comprehension that is formed from another slice.

```
>>> L = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
>>> L[1::2] = [x+5 for x in L[1::2]]
>>> L
[1, 8, 5, 12, 9, 16]
```

---

**Slicing syntax explanation**

Slicing is when you take a finite sequence, and index it with 1-2 colon characters, with the goal of selecting a *subsequence*. A slice with 1 colon character has the format:

```
[start:stop]
```

A slice with 2 colon characters has the format:

```
[start:stop:step]
```

Arguments can be omitted and then they will be set to their default values. If start is omitted, it defaults to the first index of the sequence, or 0, since Python sequences are 0-indexed. If stop is omitted it defaults to the last valid index of the sequence + 1, or equivalently, the length of the sequence. If step is omitted, it defaults to 1.

So when you do a slice like `seq[1::2]`, what you're saying is, get the elements of `seq` with indexes starting from index 1 inclusive (specified by you), stopping at index `len(seq)` exclusive (default value), and stepping by 2 every time (specified by you).

---

**List comprehension explanation**

A list comprehension can be thought of as a concise, Pythonic way to do map and filter operations on an arbitrary number of potentially nested iterations over iterables. If none of that makes sense to you, don't worry! You can learn all the map and filter stuff later. For now, just think of the list comprehension `[x+5 for x in L[1::2]]` as:

```
newlist = []
for x in L[1::2]:
    newlist.append(x+5)
```

And then `newlist` would be set to the value of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

The most readable solution for this problem without creating a new list, or using list comprehension would be to use enumerate.

```
l = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]

for i, v in enumerate(l):  # i,v = index, value
    if i % 2 != 0:         # if the index is odd
        l[i] = v + 5       # add 5 to the value
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you just want to modify your own code:

```
def main():
    L = [3,12,9,5,7,6,8]
    i=0
    while i < len(L):
        if i%2 == 1:
            print L[i]
            // i= i+5
            L[i] = L[i]+5
        elif i%2 == 0:
            print L
```

The mistake you made is you changed the temporal variable i instead of the element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close: if you wanted to go with your code, it is better to iterate the list using `for` in your case. Also, you're first printing the value and then increasing it - the printed value will therefore not be the one changed.

Improved code looks like this:

```
def main():
    L = [3,12,9,5,7,6,8]
    for i in L:
        if i%2 == 1:
            print i + 5
        elif i%2 == 0:
            print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapping a function to every odd index element will also work:

```
>>> L = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
>>> L[1::2] = map(lambda x: x + 5, L[1::2])
>>> L
[1, 8, 5, 12, 9, 16]
```

@Shashank's answer is the way I would do it, this is just so you know yet another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
x,y=1,21
for i in range (x,y,2):
print(i)
```

If you are using the 'i' as an odd number then use the range function with the step agruments the print(i) will give you the odd number series on that particular part of the range.